# Is it possible to grant access to a certain service for only a certain sub-organization unit for an App not yet listed in the Marketplace?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace, service-accounts

We are developing an app which our customer would like to install for some of their teams. However, we have not yet listed this app on the App Marketplace and would like to install this application for our client's sub-org without needing to do so. Is there any way to have the admin grant access to our app for only this sub-org?
We checked out domain wide delegation, but it seems to be for the whole domain. The only other method seems to be using OAuth, but this would involve every person individually signing up, and not a one time action by the admin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know.... no.

But you definitely could simulate that. For instance make your app completely public, but on the login page check for the IP of the logged customer and then decide if it comes from the right subdomain. If not, send the customer to a "403" page.

Or you might be able to create ONE user, using the same email for the whole organization?